# Select box 'frozen' on file screen

Tags: 3d-view

An image of the select box is frozen on a file and remains in the same place om the screen when I move view. I am unable to clear it. The select box still works. The image of the box, from a previous selection, remains on the screen in edit & object modes, and when I close & reopen the file.
I hope someone can help, I've spent days working on this file.

The issue can be seen in the images below, the white dashes below the 'A'.

Thanks

Andrew (frustrated)

[image: screenshot]

[image: close up]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you did is selecting a *Render Region*, shortcut is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>. This helps to only view certain parts of the viewport rendered after switching to rendered view in order to only have some parts/region of interest in that moment fully rendered. This can as well be used when rendering through the camera.

To clear the *Render Region* press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>.

Comment: Thank you so much Gordon, your wisdom resolved my problem. (:

Comment: @andrew You're welcome. You might consider accepting the answer ;)